# Share Devise Session across Custom Domains in Rails 5 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have a Rails 5 app that uses Devise for managing users and hosted on Heroku.

My site is called www.example.com but I allow my users to set up custom domains so it could be www.andyexample.com as well.

I can successfully login to www.example.com. However, when I login to www.example.com and then navigate to www.andyexample.com I'm not logged in anymore even though it's the same application.

Is there a way to keep me logged in even when I change between domains?

My understanding was that Devise uses cookies but since a cookie is stored in the browser, why does it not keep me logged in?

Not a duplicate to the suggested post since it's outdated and has 1 reply that introduces a fairly complex solution to something that should be easier to achieve.

Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single sign-on, multiple domains on same server, ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988764/single-sign-on-multiple-domains-on-same-server-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Seems like a complex solution for something that should be easier and a fairly normal use case.